# Configuring Intellij 14 to work with Subversion v 1.8.5 using svn+ssh

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm just making the switch to IntelliJ 14 from Eclipse. I'm having some trouble getting SVN set up. I use svn+ssh and my setup on Eclipse works fine. The Subversion server is running v1.8.5. I'm using v 1.8 in Intellij. 
I've pointed the SSH settings to use TortoisePlink.exe as my SSH executable but I'm wondering if this is necessary on IntelliJ ?? I've set my ssh username and port up. I'm logging in with password at the moment as this is what I do Eclipse (I'll probably change to private key once I have this working).
I've cleared the Auth Cache a number of times between attempts to get this working.

When I click on my the repository I've added the Authentication Required dialog appears. I login and I can browse the repository. However if I try and check the repository out with the same credentials in the Authentication Required dialog they fail and I repeatedly get asked to reenter them. Any ideas what is happening here?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem with IntelliJ 14.0.2. To get the SSH authentication to work I did the following:

1. Installed TortoiseSvn 1.8.10 (this may not be important as the key component TortoisePlink rarely changes, but I didn't want to get stuck simply because of older software).
2. Installed Collabnet subversion command line client 1.8.11 (ditto above comment).
3. I run the Pageant SSH key agent (I've always used this). My private key has a pass-phrase but Pageant requests that in order to unlock the key before caching it so this will have no impact on IntelliJ.
4. I have the SVN_SSH environment variable set to "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe".
5. In IntelliJ I opened the Settings | Version Control | Subversion | General tab and selected 'Use command line client' and set the subversion client to 'C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client\svn.exe'.
6. In IntelliJ I opened the Settings | Version Control | Subversion | SSH Settings tab and chose the 'Subversion config' option. I set the SSH Tunnel input to '$SVN_SSH' (and nothing else) and saved that.

Comment: Step 5 got me working I used sliksvn and pointed intellij there in the 'general' tab

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem because SVN 1.9.x no longer works with IntelliJ IDEA 14, so we downloaded SVN 1.8.13 and it worked with the command line client setup.